Criteria for using $\tau = I \alpha$ about particular points (simple 2D rotations)
I'm looking at the classic yoyo problem wherein a solid disk of radius $R$, mass $M$, (and thus moment of inertia $I_\text{cm} = \frac{1}{2}MR^2$) unfurls from the string coiled around it due to the pull of gravity. This is well-known and well-solved problem: the tension in the string is known to be $\frac{1}{3}Mg$, the resulting linear acceleration of the yoyo is $a = \frac{2}{3}g$ and the angular acceleration of the yoyo is $\alpha = - \frac{2g}{3R}$ (taking positive as counterclockwise). I've provided a diagram of all of these well-known results as well as three different points $A$, $B$, and $C$, which are chosen relative to the position of the yoyo at this snapshot in time, but are at rest relative to our observational frame.

Using point $A$ as the reference point, $\tau_A = -RMg$ (due to gravity only) and $I_A = \frac{3}{2}MR^2$ (via the parallel axis theorem). In this case the quantity $\frac{\tau_A}{I_A} = -\frac{2g}{3R}$ agrees with $\alpha$.
Using point $B$ as the reference point, $\tau_B = -\frac{1}{3}RMg$ (due to tension only) and $I_B = I_\text{cm} = \frac{1}{2}MR^2$. In this case the quantity $\frac{\tau_B}{I_B} = -\frac{2g}{3R}$ also agrees with $\alpha$.
However, using point $C$ as the reference point, $\tau_C = MRg - \frac{2}{3}MRg = \frac{1}{3}MRg$ (net torque from both forces) and $I_C = \frac{3}{2}MR^2$ (via the parallel axis theorem). In this case, we find $\frac{\tau_C}{I_C} = \frac{2g}{9R}$, which is clearly not $\alpha$.
Obviously, something is wrong with using point $C$ along with the relationship $\tau = I \alpha$, whereas using points $A$ and $B$ yield the correct results. What is the criteria for using $\tau = I \alpha$ that fails with point $C$ but is satisfied for points $A$ and $B$?

Let's derive $\tau = I\alpha$ to see the conditions of its validity.
At any instant, we may describe the motion of a rigid body as a rotation about an arbitrary point, on top of a translation. Specifically, the velocity of any point on the rigid body may be expressed as
$$\vec v = \vec v_0 +\vec \omega\times\vec r,$$
where $\vec v_0$ is the velocity of the center of rotation you have chosen, $\vec r$ is the relative position with respect to this point, and $\vec \omega$ is the angular velocity. Taking the derivative with respect to time,
$$\vec a = \vec  a_0 + \vec \alpha \times \vec r + \vec \omega\times (\vec v - \vec v_0)$$
$$=\vec a_0 + \vec \alpha\times \vec r + \vec \omega\times (\vec \omega \times \vec r).$$
The second term on the right hand side is the tangential acceleration, while the third term is the centripetal acceleration.
To simplify things a bit, since this is a 2D problem with the axis of rotation perpendicular to the page, I will assume that $\omega$ and $\alpha$ are both perpendicular to the page, i.e. (anti-)parallel to each other. We can break down the position vector into two components: $\vec r = \vec R + \vec r_\parallel$, where $\vec R$ is perpendicular to $\vec \omega$ (and hence the axis of rotation), and $\vec r_\parallel$ is parallel to it. Then, $\vec\alpha\times\vec r = \vec\alpha\times\vec R$ and $\vec\omega\times\vec r = \vec\omega\times\vec R$. Using the vector identity $\vec A \times (\vec B \times \vec C) = (\vec A \cdot \vec C)\vec B-(\vec A \cdot \vec B)\vec C$, we may simplify the centripetal acceleration term to obtain
$$\vec a=\vec a_0 + \vec \alpha\times \vec R-\omega ^2\vec R.$$
Now to get the out-of-plane component of the torque,
$$\require{cancel}\vec \tau =\int\rho(\vec r)\vec R\times \vec a \ dV$$
$$=\left(\int\rho\vec R\ dV\right)\times \vec a_0 + \int\rho\vec R\times (\vec \alpha \times \vec R) \ dV - \int\rho\omega^2\cancelto{0}{(\vec R \times \vec R)}\ dV$$
$$=\left(\int\rho\vec R\ dV\right)\times \vec a_0 + \left(\int\rho R^2\ dV\right)\vec\alpha$$
$$=M\vec R_\text{CM}\times\vec a_0 + I\vec\alpha$$
or
$$\tau - M\vec R_\text{CM}\times\vec a_0 = I\vec\alpha.$$
We see that $\vec\tau = I\vec \alpha$ holds if only if $- M\vec R_\text{CM}\times\vec a_0 = 0$, where $\vec R_\text{CM}$ is the position of the center of mass relative to the reference point you pick. $- M\vec R_\text{CM}\times\vec a_0$ is the fictitious torque term that you need to account for to be able to use $\vec\tau = I\vec\alpha$ around an arbitrary point.
If you pick $A$, this point has no downward acceleration, so $-M\vec R_\text{CM}\times\vec a_0 = 0.$ If you pick $B$ (the center of mass), $\vec R_\text{CM} = 0$, so $-M\vec R_\text{CM}\times\vec a_0 = 0.$ Finally, for point $C$, the downward (tangential) component of $\vec a_0$ is $-2\alpha R$, so $-M\vec R_\text{CM}\times\vec a_0$ is $2MR^2\alpha$, out-of-plane (counter-clockwise). We can write in the counter-clockwise direction
$$\tau_C + 2MR^2\alpha = I_C \alpha.$$
Plugging in $\tau_C = \frac13MRg$ and $I_C=\frac32MR^2$, we find the correct result $\alpha = -\frac{2g}{3R}$.

Thank you! I've been having trouble locating a proof or mention of the relationship $\tau_C + 2MR^2\alpha = I_C \alpha$ as you have derived here. This is excellent, and I will be looking forward to analyzing this a bit closer.

Can you explain a little more how you equated $\frac{d}{dt} \vec R$ with $\vec v - \vec v_0$? This equality seems odd to me as $\vec v - \vec v_0 = \vec \omega \times \vec R$ is of course perpendicular to $\vec \omega$, but in general despite $\vec R$ being perpendicular to $\vec \omega$, the derivative $\frac{d}{dt} \vec R$ wouldn't necessarily be perpendicular to $\vec \omega$, no? Are we implicitly assuming in this proof that $\vec \omega$ doesn't change direction?

Similarly, it looks like you used the fact that $\vec \alpha \perp \vec R$ when you write $\vec R \times (\vec \alpha \times \vec R) = R^2 \alpha$, which I think also stems from assuming $\vec \omega$ isn't changing direction.

Final question: the torque $\vec \tau$ that you computed through your integral is computed specifically relative to the axis of rotation, since $\vec R$ represents the positions of particles relative to the axis of rotation in the plane perpendicular to $\vec \omega$. Doesn't mean that the formula $\tau - M\vec R_\text{CM}\times\vec a_0 = I\vec\alpha$ is only applicable to one point—the axis of rotation, which I believe here is $A$?


I did assume that $\omega$ doesn't change direction to simplify things here, and I've edited the answer to make this clear. We can proceed without this assumption, but there will be other terms to deal with. There are additional complications such as the fact $\mathbf I\vec\alpha$ can generally point in a different direction than $\vec\alpha$. We skirt these by only considering the torque components outside the plane. 2. Yes, $\vec R\times(\vec\alpha\times\vec R)=R^2\vec\alpha$ assumes $\vec\alpha\cdot\vec R=0$, consistent with the assumption $\vec\alpha\parallel\vec\omega$.



The motion of a rigid body can always be instantaneously decomposed into translation plus a rotation about any point. The choice of this point, and hence the axis of rotation, is arbitrary, so you aren't restricted to point $A$. In other words, the axis of rotation need not be at rest.


That's a really good point regarding #3. I will have to mull over this some more, but overall this seems like a robust argument, then! Thank you very much once again.

@TrevorKafka
About your question in the comment: the vectors here are actually in 3D space. The "plane" is where you draw your yoyo graph.

$\vec{\omega} \parallel \vec{\alpha} \parallel \vec{\tau}$ are all in the same direction, pointing out of the plane, along the rotating axis.
Since $\vec{R}$ is in the plane, $\frac{d}{dt}\vec{R}$ is also in the plane.  Obviously $\vec{\omega} \perp \frac{d}{dt}\vec{R}$.



Since $\vec{R}_{CM}$ and $\vec{a_0}$ are both in the plane, the cross product is pointing out of the plane, which is parallel to the $\vec{\tau}$.
If you evaluate this additional term carefully, $M\vec{R}_{CM} \times \vec{a_0}$ is same as the torque of the fiction force in the answer of @Farcher


@Puk Thank you very much for your reply! This is all extremely helpful.

Newton's second law works in frames of reference which are not accelerating.
If an accelerating frame of reference is chosen then a fictional force acting at the centre of mass has to be added to enable Newton's second law to be used.
When doing such problems points $A$ and/or $B$ are usually chosen because:

point $A$ is not acceleration and so no fictitious force is needed, and

point $B$ has a downward acceleration of $2g/3$, and a fictitious force $2Mg/3$ acting at the centre of mass upwards is added but contributes zero torque about the centre of mass, $B$.


Point $C$ has a downward acceleration of $4g/3$ downwards, and a fictitious force $4Mg/3$ acting at the centre of mass upwards is added.
$\tau_{\rm C} = I_{\rm C} \,\alpha \Rightarrow \frac 13 Mg\cdot 2R+\frac 43 Mg\cdot R -Mg\cdot R= \frac 32 MR^2 \cdot \alpha\Rightarrow \alpha = \dfrac{2g}{3R}$
Note that this is no different to your diagram being rotated anticlockwise and representing a cylinder rolling down a slope without slipping.

Even though the object is accelerating, I'm imagining $C$ as being fixed in space, not fixed to the yoyo, so I'm not entirely convinced by this argument, to be honest.

When you write “fixed in space” are you then asking about an inertial reference frame?

Yes, I am imagining point $C$ as fixed in the observational inertial frame and the yoyo is just passing through.

Then that is the same, instantaneous, as point $A$ as points $A$ and $C$ are not moving relative to one another.

That seems at odds with "point $C$ has a downward acceleration of $4g/3$ downwards." How do you explain a fictitious force as seen from an inertial frame of reference?

There is no factitious force in an inertial frame. In an accelerating from fictitious forces are added for the sole purpose of enabling the use of Newton's second law. Have a read of the answers to the question If centrifugal force is fictitious, what force is real in its stead?

Yes, that's basically my point. It sounds to me that you are claiming that your argumentation that hinges on fictitious forces also applies when making computations about an inertial point $C$, which is what seems at odds.

Point C attached to yo-yo is accelerating and so is a frame of reference attached to point C. Hence to use Newton’s second law in that reference frame fictions forces need to be introduced.

it's not attached to the yoyo. I mentioned that in the original post as well as in one of my comments above.
